# Colorbox's close button on IOS's Safari makes the phone think I'm pressing one of its tray buttons

Tags: javascript, ios, colorbox, tray

I tested my site out on an iPhone and one of the many problems I encountered was the Colorbox close button not functioning because it would instead bring up some sort of Safari tray.

Is there any way around this without making the Colorbox smaller?

Version of Colorbox: 1.6.1

Comment: Solutions to these kinds of issues are usually hidden in the details somewhere. Add the problematic code to your post so folks can help you work through the issue.

Comment: I've added the version of Colorbox.